# Need clarification onto the intuition of why every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

So you can have a function on (a,b) that is not uniformly continuous, but as soon as you ADD points to the domain it becomes uniformly continuous.. I've read through the technical arguments and can follow them, yet something seems rather peculiar still. Like, you're adding points, so it seems it should be harder to find a delta that works for everything, you know?

So it must be that there is something special about the points added. I'd appreciate clarity on this matter! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're radically changing the topology by adding the end points. But just because you add points doesn't mean much is going to change. Consider $(a-1,b+1)$

Comment: It seems you are not understanding the definitions. Your first sentence is false, for instance.

Comment: If a set is closed then limit processes inside the set will never let you get out of that set (the door is closed for all limit processes). Thereby you have a handle to (control over) whatever happens in a closed set. For open sets this is not the case. Having a closed and bounded set gives even more control and nice behavior because then you don't have the infinities. This is as far as I can think of compact sets in intuitive manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if a function is uniformly continuous in $[a,b]$ then it is uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$ as well. So if a function is **not** uniformly continuous in an open interval $(a,b)$ it means you can't simply "add points" and extend this function continuously to the closed interval $[a,b]$. Look for example at $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in $(0,1]$. It is not uniformly continuous and you can't simply define it the point $x=0$ to make it continuous. It is impossible.

Comment: And adding points 0 and 1 to $(0,1)$ then gaurentee's that any function on this set, which is now $[0,1]$, is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Any continuous function in $[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous in this set, not every function in general.